# how to read .dbf files in talend 2020?

Tags: database, talend, visual-foxpro, dbf

i am new in talend open studio and i found no way to read **dbf files**  .

i found actually 2 blocking ways where i am stuck each time with different errors .

i tried first to downlaod from exchange.talend , tDBFInput component and it shows  an exception  "dbflib.CorruptedTable**Exception**: **Number of field descriptions in file could not be calculated**" each time i try to run the job after putting the dbf file in that componenet .

i also tried to perform a jdbc connection using a dbf driver i downloaded , after installing it as external jar , i cannot find out the driver class , i can select the driver and it is added from the list of drivers but  i  cannot find the class ,which class to use .and also how to later on make the connection to a file not a table .

i also tried a second tDBFInput component that i downloaded from the exchange.talend web site but it always shows MASHAPE KEY that i need to configure , where i have no idea what value it should take , i see people saying it should be an URL pointing to an API and you also must know the authentication needed to request that url  .

[i even tried to find solution in edureka](https://www.edureka.co/community/96246/how-to-read-dbf-files-in-talend-2020) but no solution found .my question was detailed there with screen shots .

can anyone who extracted data from dbf FOX pro files in  version 7.x tell me how to do it?

Comment: I don't use talend but a quıck search shows it has support for oledb. Then you could use OLEDB with VFPOLEDB driver.

Comment: thank you for the information but i already saw things like that ; i don't know how to properly use VFPOLEDB driver in talend and from where to download a valide version of that VFPOLEDB driver

Comment: You can download it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839